# UIButton if statement swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want the button to go to the QaController if the word Hello is typed otherwise I want the alert to appear and then go back to the home screen (viewController) but it doesn't seem to work

```
@IBAction func submitButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if TextField.text.containsString("Hello"){
        let secondViewController:QaController = QaController()
        self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Thank You!", message:
            "We appreciate your feedback!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        let homeViewController:ViewController = ViewController()
        self.presentViewController(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The code works fine without the IF statements so I'm not sure whats wrong :/

What goes wrong is when I click Submit, when I put "Hello" in it shows a black screen with no error message, instead of displaying the correct view

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to work` What does this mean: is there an error message, if yes which one? What was expected to happen and what happened instead? Please always give context and details. Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you using storyboards? If so, you need to instantiate from the storyboard instead: storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(CONTROLLERIDENTIFIERINSTORYBOARDASSTRING). You might be creating a controller without an UI.

Comment: first check your textfield having content or not ,using print.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are comparing your string with lower case, May be your text field value is `"hello"` not equal to `"Hello"`. So please compare like

```
if(TextField.text!.caseInsensitiveCompare("Hello") == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame)
{ 
    // do your stuff
}
else{
        print(TextField.text)
    }
```

Hope it will help you.